# Mint boot going on loop

Tags: linux-mint, boot, virtual-machine, login

I have been using Mint 20.1. Today I was trying to install Android-studio, which involved installing quite a few packages. I needed virtualisation so following instructions, I installed a checker app (KVM checker) which informed that the vistualisation was not enabled (in bios) and my processor supported it.

After enabling virtualisation, I have been unable to login.

I have tried disabling virtualisation in bios, enabled/ disabled intel security setting in bios as well, to no avail. I followed the instructions to check for free space on the Mint drive & can confirm that I have over 50GB free. I also cleared tmp folder and deleted the `.Xauthority` file. I also deleted the commands I had added to PATH variable within `.bashrc` & `.zshrc` files pointing to android-studio/bin folder.

What am I missing please.

**EDIT:**
I ran the command `sudo dmesg` to review the boot logs and there is these errors:

```
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 619333 [IBUS]
```

This above error is logged every time I try to login from gui.

**EDIT 2:**

Journalctl output: https://pastebin.com/90BraZ1e

Dmesg: https://pastebin.com/5uv8fDCu

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems as if you have a nvidia card, you might want to boot with `rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau` to disable the driver and after you log in, install the `nvidia-driver` package like [so](https://itsfoss.com/nvidia-linux-mint/)

To boot with the blacklist option, you need to hit <kbd>e</kbd> when grub shows you the options. Then find the end of the line where `quiet` is and put in the option after it. To boot use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I tried your steps to book with nouveau blacklisted, however, when I tried to login from gui, it again logged the same error

Comment: Then try to boot with nomodeset, which makes sure that no graphics driver gets loaded at all. But I don't think that that's related to you not being able to login. Please attach the output of journalctl --system --user -S today to your main post. You can just pipe the output into a file with "> file"

Comment: Thank you @modzilla. I have updated the question with link to pastebin for the output of both journalctl & dmesg.

Comment: you might want to have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239503/ubuntu-20-04-and-20-10-etc-securetty-no-such-file-or-directory) Otherwise try to reinstall lightdm by running apt install --reinstall lightdm

Comment: I should have added that I installed latest nvidia drivers as per the link you shared above using the command `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. This seems to have rid of the error `[IRBUS]`. However, now its hibernation being not supported error.

Comment: I will try the lightdm installation first and see how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunately, both (copy & reinstall lightdm) did not work. How there are two errors main in `sudo dmesg`: `xorg: raw io port access is resticted; see man kernal_lockdown7`, followed by the same `systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted`

Comment: I don't know then. Reinstalling might be faster. Last thing I would try, would be to add a new user with `export USRNAME=<UserName>; useradd -m -G sudo,wheel $USRNAME && passwd $USRNAME` and try logging in with that one. If that works you can try to migrate the home-Folder

Comment: You have been very generous with your time and effort. Thanks Modzilla. In the end I was about to over-write the drive with reinstall when I realised that Timeshift is enabled. I restored last week's version and its working now.

Comment: I checked the logs of updates and my suspicious is that the latest version of python and systemmd updates may have something to do with this problem.

Comment: I'm glad that it's working now and that you had a backup of the files :)